# How to access app directory programmatically in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, database

If we create a database file programmatically, it will store in somewhere in `/Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/DB425A55-5008-44D2-B08D-C21AFFBAF935/Documents`. For this, we have to use below code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.db"];
```

Is there any way to create and store database files in our local app folder?

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about your app's bundle - you can get details about this by reading the documentation for the `NSBundle` class.

However, you only have read access to this - you can read the contents of file in the bundle but you can't change them etc. This is beacuse your bundle is signed and if you were able to change it then the certificates checksums etc wouldn't work :)

Why do you specifically want to write into your app's folder? What's wrong with the other directories provided for your app?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got info from NSBundle. I just wanted to use an existing db file, so i thought to place it in app directory. Basically i am new to iPhone, i don't know other better places. :)

Comment: The code in your question is the perfect place to put your app's data :) And if you wanted to start with your db already containing stuff then you can ship it in your bundle and copy it into `NSDocumentDirectory` the first time your app starts up - it's then read/write so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make changes/add to your app bundle.